# Is getting the General ID same as getting FormattedID in rally?

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

I am trying to get the ID under "General" from a feature item in rally. This is my query:

`body = { "find" => {"_ProjectHierarchy" => projectID, "_TypeHierarchy" =>               "PortfolioItem/Feature"
     },
     "fields" => ["FormattedID","Name","State","Release","_ItemHierarchy","_TypeHierarchy","Tags"],
     "hydrate" => ["_ItemHierarchy","_TypeHierarchy","Tags"],
     "fetch"=>true
      }`

I am not able to get any value for FormattedID, I tried using "_UnformattedID" but it pulls up an entirely different value than the FormattedID. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LBAPI does not have FormattedID field. You are correct using _UnformattedID.  It is the FormattedID without the prefix. For example, this query:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/1111/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"_ProjectHierarchy":2222,"_TypeHierarchy":"PortfolioItem/Feature","State":"Developing",_ValidFrom: {$gte: "2013-06-01TZ",$lt: "2013-09-01TZ"}},sort:{_ValidFrom:-1}}&fields=["_UnformattedID","Name","State"]&hydrate=["State"]&compress=true&pagesize:200
```

shows _UnformattedID that correspond to FormattedID as this screenshot shows:

[image]

I noticed your are using `fields` and `fetch` . Per [LBAPI's documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc), it uses `fields` rather than `fetch`. If you want to get all fields, use `fields=true`

As far as the missing custom fields, make sure that the custom field value was set within the dates of the query.

Compare these almost identical queries: the first query does not return a custom field, the second query does.

Query #1:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/1111/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"_ProjectHierarchy":2222,"_TypeHierarchy":"PortfolioItem/Feature","State":"Developing",_ValidFrom: {$gte: "2013-06-01TZ",$lt: "2013-09-01TZ"}}}&fields=["_UnformattedID","Name","State","c_PiCustomField"]&hydrate=["State","c_PiCustomField"]
```

Query #2:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/11111/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"_ProjectHierarchy":2222,"_TypeHierarchy":"PortfolioItem/Feature","State":"Developing",__At: "current"}&fields=["_UnformattedID","Name","State","c_PiCustomField"]&hydrate=["State","c_PiCustomField"]
```

The first query uses time period: `_ValidFrom: {$gte: "2013-06-01TZ",$lt: "2013-09-01TZ"}`

The second query uses `__At: "current"`

Let's say I just create a new custom field on PortfolioItem. It is not possible to create a custom field on PorfolioItem/Feature, so the field is created on PI, but both queries still use `"_TypeHierarchy":"PortfolioItem/Feature"`.

After I created this custom field, called PiCustomField, I set a value of that field for a specific Feature, F4.

The first query does not have a single snapshot that includes that field because that field did not exist in the time period we lookback. We can't change the past.

The second query returns this field for F4. It does not return it for other Features because all other Features do not have this field set.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: In my case, the value returned by UnformmatedID is completely different from the "General ID" field value

Comment: When i try to fetch all items using fields => true, I just get one custom field called c_Category, what I am looking for is other custom variables like c_AssignedProgram, c_ScopingTeam, c_AspirationalRelease . I am not able to pull up any of these values. Do you think it has got anything to do with the "_TypeHierarchy" that I am using? Here's a link to my complete code:
[link](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6124432/)

Comment: Is there any other type that I need to use to get the other custom fields?

Comment: I suggest testing your query, and making it work in the browser first before writing it in the ruby code. Are c_AssignedProgram, c_ScopingTeam, c_AspirationalRelease custom fields of PortfolioItem/Feature ? Your query specifies only PortfolioItem/Feature, and those fields must belong to that work item type.

Comment: what do you mean by making it work in browser? ALl the custom fields that I need are of PortfolioItem (not PortfolioItem/Feature). I tried changing it, but still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: By testing in the browser I mean that you may build the query (similar to the example I have in my post, just replace OIDs) and paste it in the address bar of the browser, and examine JSON that comes back, and then continue fine tuning the query to widen or narrow depending on what you want to get. But all this testing can be done in the browser. You don't even need a browser REST client for it, but a browser plugin that makes JSON pretty is very useful. rally_api does not have a built-in support for Lookback API yet, but even if it did, verifying the query results in the browser helps.

Comment: I edited my answer to add information related to the problem of custom fields not showing up that you mentioned in your last comment.

Comment: Since you mentioned about testing in the browser, I am using SSO to access Rally ( I don't have direct access to rally through the link).